# possible bug in geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

i was hoping to plot two time series and shade the space between the series according to which series is larger at that time.

here are the two series-- first in a data frame  with an indicator for whichever series is larger at that time

```
d1 <- read.csv("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/0txm3f70msd3nm6/ribbon%20data.csv?dl=1")
```

And this is the melted series.

```
d2 <- read.csv("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6ohwmtkhpsutpig/melted%20ribbon%20data.csv?dl=1")
```

which I plot...

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data = d2,
                 aes(x = time, y = value, group = variable, color = variable)) +
         geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
         geom_ribbon(data = d1[d1$big == "B",],
                     aes(x = time, ymin = csa, 
                         ymax =  csb),
                         alpha  = .25,
                         fill = "#9999CC") +
         geom_ribbon(data = d1[d1$big == "A",],
                     aes(x = time, ymin = csb, 
                         ymax =  csa),
                     alpha  = .25,
                     fill = "#CC6666") +
         scale_color_manual(values = c("#CC6666" , "#9999CC"))
```

which results in...

[image: the resulting plot]

why is there a superfluous blue band in the middle of the plot?

Comment: It's because you have a gap in the data. To tell `ggplot` about this gap, and to plot nothing, you have to terminate the ribbon by adding a row of NA data at the end of each "section".

Comment: i'm actually not sure that's it, because these are just two simulated random walk series. why are there no red bands between their ribbons?

Comment: I second the comment of @Andrie. The plot is correct. The ribbon connects the data points. If you want to remove the gap, you have to create separate ribbons.

Comment: There are no red bands because at the "edges" of the `d1$big == "A"` data the differences between `csa` and `csb` are always zero. This does *not* hold for `d1$big == "B"`.

Comment: thanks @Andrie and Sven-- the elegance of your criticism alluded me at first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution. I replaced `data = d1[d1$big == "B",]` in the first `geom_ribbon` function with:

```
data = rbind(d1[d1$big == "B",],
             d1[c((which(diff(as.numeric(d1$big)) == -1) + 1),
                  (which(diff(as.numeric(d1$big)) == 1))), ])
```

This is necessary since the first and last rows of `d1$big == "B"` sequences often contain different `csa` and `csb` values. As a result, there is a visible ribbon connecting the data. The above command uses the last rows before and the first rows after these sequences together with the data for the first ribbon.
This problem does not exist for `d1$big == "A"` (the base for the second ribbon).

The complete code:

```
ggplot() +
 geom_line(data = d2,
           aes(x = time, y = value, group = variable, color = variable)) +
 geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
 geom_ribbon(data = rbind(d1[d1$big == "B",],
                          d1[c((which(diff(as.numeric(d1$big)) == -1) + 1),
                               (which(diff(as.numeric(d1$big)) == 1))), ]),
             aes(x = time, ymin = csa, ymax =  csb),
             alpha  = .25, fill = "#9999CC") +
 geom_ribbon(data = d1[d1$big == "A",],
             aes(x = time, ymin = csb, ymax =  csa),
             alpha  = .25, fill = "#CC6666") +
 scale_color_manual(values = c("#CC6666" , "#9999CC"))
```

[image]

Comment: I had no clue how to include this for my own plot, I ended up making two new columns, 1 above and 1 below the line, filling the spaces with NA's. This worked flawlessly