# Calculating the area between two curves in a time series, based on two groups

Tags: r

I need help calculating the total area between two curves for a set of timeseries data in R.
I have a column based on date, another that plots the lowest value at that time (low value), and one that plots the highest value at that time, based on two groups (1,2). To clarify, I want to compare the differences between both groups.

Here is the link to a plot that is essentially what I also have. I need to calculate the area of each color in this plot. I based my code almost entirely on this post.
Here is my code in ggplot

```
df_viz3 <-df_daily_wide|>mutate(min_line = pmin(Field, Prairie))  |> pivot_longer(c(Field, Prairie), names_to = "group", values_to = "y")

ggplot(data = df_viz3, aes(x = date_fixed)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = y, ymin = min_line, fill = group)) +
  labs(y = "Mean Daily Water", x = "Date") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 week",date_labels = "%m/%d")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("aquamarine3", "slategray3")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("aquamarine3", "slategray3")) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date_fixed, y = rain/10), color = "skyblue2") +
  scale_y_continuous("Mean Daily Water Content (m3/m3)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~. * 1, name = "Rainfall (1/10 cm)"))
```

[image]

​
[Fill area between two lines, with high/low and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318391/fill-area-between-two-lines-with-high-low-and-dates)

```
date_fixed  min_line    group   y
5/23/2023   0.3218662   Field   0.3218662
5/23/2023   0.3218662   Prairie 0.3232029
5/24/2023   0.2842907   Field   0.3098835
5/24/2023   0.2842907   Prairie 0.2842907
5/25/2023   0.29184722  Field   0.32617778
5/25/2023   0.29184722  Prairie 0.29184722
5/26/2023   0.27190409  Field   0.30230691
5/26/2023   0.27190409  Prairie 0.27190409
5/27/2023   0.24828009  Field   0.26705671
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: How can we suggest how you might modify your code when you don't share your code? (You reference a post with *similar* but not *identical* code and don't specify how you have modified it.)  Also, I am not sure if you want differences between high and low within group or between groups for high/low values.  In either case, since you have no observations with both groups recorded on the same date, the answer you desire is unclear.  Based on your test data, what numerical results do you expect?

Comment: If you have daily data (with no missing dates), isn't this just `df_viz3 %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(area = sum(y - min_line))`?  If you have missing dates, then you will need to decide how to interpolate.  [Thank you for updating your question after my earlier comment.]